# Convert list of values in SQL to CTE or Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert a list of values like (value1, value2, value3, ...., value500)
to a temp table or cte?

One way would be to do:

```
WITH huge_list_cte AS (
   Select value1
   UNION
   Select value2 ...
)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Where is the list of values coming from?  Can you create a series of `insert into #temp (field_name) values (value1)` statements?  What do you want to do with the values once you have them in a database?  Your answer will help shape the responses (CTE vs Temp Table).

Comment: You could get a large string split function (or use `string_split` in SQL 2016) which takes a string and splits it into a table based on separator values. Most of these allow the output to be used directly as a table.

Comment: you can avoid typing 500 select/union/column doing a dynamic query. And I'm not talking about dynamic execution of the query, but just to print the query

Comment: You can manually create a temp table, and use an `INSERT INTO ... Values(..),(...),(...)...` statement (NOTE: Must be split into a maximum of 1000 rows per insert statement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `values`:

```
WITH huge_list_cte AS (
      SELECT v
      FROM (VALUES (value1), (value2), . . . ) v(v)
     )
. . .
```

Comment: Only works if the number of entries in the values list is <= 1000.

Comment: Can I do this without wrapping each value in round brackets?

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper . . . The parentheses are needed for the syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Got it thanks. My hope was that if the SQL engine can interpret (a,b,c) as a list of values, there would be a way to take (a,b,c) and either select directly from it, or convert it to another data structure.

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper . . . Lists are not a type in SQL.  They are really only part of `IN` expressions.  (Many databases would interpret that construct as a *tuple* not a list.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` variable

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(Id INT);
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (101), (102) ...
```

Then you can use it in your queries as normal table

```
SELECT * FROM @Data
```

You can even create predefined table type and reuse it [Microsoft Docs: table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of values (value1, value2,...value500) as a huge string..
you can first assign that to a variable and then use a split list kind of function and then pass the variable to the function.

This is how you could use it

```
declare @input varchar(max) = ('value1,value2,value3,value499,value500')
select * from dbo.SplitList (@input,',')
```

The function I use is this:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitList](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (value nvarchar(4000))
AS
--this function takes two parameters; the first is the delimited string, the second is the delimiter

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @INDEX INT
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)
    -- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
    --     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
    SELECT @INDEX = 1

    IF @String IS NULL RETURN
    WHILE @INDEX !=0


        BEGIN    
            -- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
            SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
            -- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
            IF @INDEX !=0
                SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
            ELSE
                SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
            -- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
            INSERT INTO @Results(value) VALUES(@SLICE)
            -- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
            SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
            -- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
            IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
    END

    RETURN
END
```

This returns a table with all your values in it.